# The difference between "last year" and "the last year" in context

Tags: difference

Tell me please what is the difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> **Last year** was tough, but somehow we managed to pull through it.
>
> **The last year** was tough, but somehow we managed to pull though it.

Comment: If you're referring to *the year preceding time of utterance*, both versions are equivalent and interchangeable (but the article-less version is far more common). If you're talking about the final year within some *past* sequence (the final year of your marriage, which eventually ended in divorce a decade ago), you need the article. For reasons I can't precisely articulate (something to do with "currency", relevance to time of speaking?) I'd normally expect a Perfect verb form in ***The*** (or ***This***) *last year **has been** tough...*

Comment: I am writing this on 31 Jan 2020, in which context I would personally say "**Last year**..." implies 1 Jan 2019 - 31 Dec 2020, whereas "**The last year**..." implies 31 Jan 2019 - 31 Jan 2020.   This is just how I take it, I doubt everybody would agree.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu  You are technically correct. (The best kind of "correct.") But in common usage it is ambiguous. So in a situation where it mattered it would be a good idea to be very specific, even if it comes out less pleasing.  "The preceding 12 months" or "the year 2019"  for example.